# Trying to write a simple loop

Tags: perl

Could someone help me with a loop please. I'm meant to be writing a program which simply asks you to guess a number between 1 and 10. If it's not the correct answer you get another chance, etc.

I can get my script to print correct/not correct one time, but how do I add into this script a possibility for the user to try again (until they guess the right number)?

Here's my basic script, which I'm sure is very simplistic and probably full of errors. Could someone help me sort out this simple problem?

Sorry for the bad layout, but I don't understand how to place my script on this site, sorry!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello, I've thought of a number, do you know what number it is?\n";
sleep (1);
print "Try and guess, type in a number between 1 and 10!\n";
my $div = <STDIN>;
my $i = 0;
my $int = int(rand (10)) + 1;
chomp $div;
if  ($div < $int) {
    print ("The number I though of is higher than $div, try again?\n");
}

if ($div > $int) {
    print ("The number I though of is lower that $div, try again?\n");
}

if ($div == $int) {
    print ("Amazing, you've guessed mt number\n");
}
```

Comment: You don't have a loop there, though you seem to know that you need a loop. What exactly do you want to know? The syntax of loops?

Comment: I'm going to try out the until loop and see if that's what I need. I guess it is.

Comment: I recently presented a feature-rich implementation of “guess my number” on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23556/21609). You might want to look there for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more straightforward approach would be a [`while` loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello, I've thought of a number, do you know what number it is?\n";
sleep (1);
my $int = int(rand (10)) + 1;
print "Try and guess, type in a number between 1 and 10!\n";

while (my $div = <STDIN>) {
  chomp $div;
  if  ($div < $int) {
      print "The number I though of is higher than $div, try again?\n";
  } 
  elsif ($div > $int) {
    print "The number I though of is lower that $div, try again?\n";
  }
  else {
    print "Amazing, you've guessed mt number\n";
    last;
  }
}
```

While (pun intended) your code already is very good (you are using `strict` and `warnings` and there are no syntax errors, yay for that!) there are some things I changed, and some more where I would suggest improvement.

But first, let's look at the loop. The program will stay in the `while` loop as long as the condition is true. Since everything the user can input (even an empty line) is considered true by Perl, this is forever. Which is fine, as there is a condition to exit the loop. It's in the `else` part of the `if`. The `last` statement tells Perl to exit the loop. If the `else` is not executed, it will go back to the start of the `while` block and the user has to try again. Forever.

The changes I made:
- You don't need `$i` as you did not use it
- You used three seperate `if` statements. Since only one of the three conditions can be true in this case, I merged them into one
- No need for the parens `()` with `print`

Suggestions:
- You should name your variables for what they do, not what they are. `$int` is not a good name. I'd go with `$random`, or even `$random_number`. Verbosity is important if you have to come back to your code at a later point.
- There is a [function called `say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) that you can enable with `use feature 'say';`. It adds `say "stuff"` as an equivalent to `print "stuff\n"`.

---

**Edit:**

If you want to add other conditions that do not directly relate to which number the user has entered, you can add another `if`.

```
while (my $div = <STDIN>) {
  chomp $div;

  if ($div eq 'quit') {
    print "You're a sissy... the number was $int. Goodbye.\n";
    last;
  }

  if ($div < $int) {
      print "The number I though of is higher than $div, try again?\n";
  } 
  elsif ($div > $int) {
    print "The number I though of is lower that $div, try again?\n";
  }
  else {
    print "Amazing, you've guessed mt number\n";
    last;
  }
}
```

You can also add a check to make sure the user has entered a number. Your current code will produce warnings if a word or letter was is entered. To do that, you will need a regular expression. Read up on them in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). The `m//` is the [match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) that works together with `=~`. The `\D` matches any character that is not a number (0 to 9). [`next`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html) steps over the rest of the `while` block and begins with the check of the `while` condition.

```
while (my $div = <STDIN>) {
  chomp $div;

  if ($div =~ m/\D/) {
    print "You may only guess numbers. Please try again.\n";
    next;
  }

  # ...
}
```

Thus, the complete check means 'look at the stuff the user has entered, and if there is anything else than a number in it at all, complain and let him try again'.

Comment: That's fantastic, I was - without knowing it - closer than I realised. Thank you very much. I'm having to learn Perl in my university class and sometimes it's a little frustrating as you understand what you have to do, but don't know what 'command' you need to get it done. You helped me solve my problem perfectly, most grateful. I'll re-read your comments again so as to be really clear on this loop.

Comment: Just a few comments and questions. a) The 'int' was something I was going to use, and then forgot to take out - a mistake on my part. b) can you use 'if' or 'elsif' more than once? I notice, as you explain, that I didn't need all those 'if' commands. However let's say I wished to add another factor such as 'if' the player hasn't guessed after 10 tries .. then exit loop. Would I just add another 'if' or 'elsif'? c) Yes, you are completely right to add that I should name my variables correctly. The program was originally in French, hence the bad (or confusing) naming of variables.

Comment: Which university do you go to that offers Perl? I'd suggest you get the *[Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do)* book by Randal L. Schwartz. It's the best one for beginners. Whichever book you get, make sure it is the newest edition. There are a lot of old, outdated things out there. Furthermore, disregard any tutorial you find that does not have `strict` and `warnings` or doesn't declare vars with `my`. Those are way old, and are best ignored. Refer to http://perl-tutorial.org/ for a list of high-quality tutorials.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in Belgium at the UCL in Louvain-la-Neuve. They teach Perl as part of the linguistics section. However, I'm  musicologist and hope to use Perl to help me research documents and music score. However, I have to learn it first, hence the simple loop questions!

Comment: I got the 'Learning Pearl' book. It's seems excellent, but unfortunately the course (at the Uni) and the book don't always match - i.e. the information isn't given in the same order.

Comment: The perl documentation (which I have linked to multiple times above) is great. There are perlfaq pages that might do a lot of work for you, and there is also [the CPAN](https://metacpan.org/). The Perl community is very strong. You can get help here and on IRC in #perl at irc.freenode.org. Welcome to the Perl World and Welcome to SO. Please also take some time to look at the SO [faq].

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow up those links.

Answer (score 2):

use an until loop

```
my $guessed = 0; 
do {
    print "Try and guess, type in a number between 1 and 10!\n";

    my $div = <STDIN>;

    ...;

    if ($div == $int) {

        print ("Amazing, you've guessed mt number\n");
        $guessed = 1;

    }
} until ($guessed)
```

Comment: Great, I'll try this and see what I can get to happen. If I understand correctly I scrap my original script, which is probably clumsy?

Comment: Ok, I back again. Could you explain 'where' I place this loop please. Thanks very much.